# Split a string by spaces using regex

Tags: node.js, regex, coffeescript

Suppose I have a string `str = "a b c d e"` . `str.split(' ')` gives me an array of the elements [a,b,c,d,e]. 
How do i use regex to get this match?

eg:
str.match(/some regex/) gives ['a','b','c','d','e']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you could try `const regex = /(\w+)/g;`

This captures any word (which is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_]) characters one or more times.  This assumes you can have items in your space separated string that are more than one character long.

Here's an example I made in regex101:

```
const regex = /(\w+)/g;
const str = `a b c d efg  17 q q q`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The String.split() supports regex as the param;

[String.prototype.split([separator[, limit]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
let str = 'a b c d e';
str.split(/ /);
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]

let str = 'a01b02c03d04e';
str.split(/\d+/);
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
```